# Passing loop count into ajax success anon function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the example below `key` is equal to the length of `d1.periods` everytime. Is their a better way besides passing `key` into `data` as a `post` variable, to get `key` into `successes` anonymous function?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/dates.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(d1){
    $('#scan-interactive').removeClass('disabled');
    for(var key in d1.periods){

      var html = "";
      html += '<tr id="'+d1.periods[key].id+'">';
      html += '<td class="month">'+d1.periods[key].month+'</td>';
      html += '<td class="week">'+d1.periods[key].week+'</td>';
      html += '<td class="days">'+d1.periods[key].days+'</td>';
      html += '<td class="dates">'+d1.periods[key].dates+'</td>';
      html += '<td class="open"></td>';
      html += '<td class="refunded"></td>';
      html += '<td class="closed"></td>';
      html += "</tr>";
      $('#scan-interactive table tbody').append(html);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'api/count.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:{'created_at_min':d1.periods[key].created_at_min,'created_at_max':d1.periods[key].created_at_max},
        success: function(d2){
          $('#'+d1.periods[key].id+" .open").html(d2.open);
          $('#'+d1.periods[key].id+" .closed").html(d2.closed);
          $('#'+d1.periods[key].id+" .returns").html(d2.returns);                  
        }
      });

    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap it in a closure:

```
(function(key){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/count.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{'created_at_min':d1.periods[key].created_at_min,'created_at_max':d1.periods[key].created_at_max},
    success: function(d2){
      $('#'+d1.periods[key].id+" .open").html(d2.open);
      $('#'+d1.periods[key].id+" .closed").html(d2.closed);
      $('#'+d1.periods[key].id+" .returns").html(d2.returns);                  
    }
  });

})(key);
```

Comment: Brilliant, I never remember to use closures.

Comment: Wouldn't `key` already be accessible because you are already inside the closure scope of the outer `ajax` success call where `key` is defined?

Comment: @Zero21xxx: Yes, it's accessible, but it changes. When the callback methods are called, the loop has already ended, and all callbacks will use the last key. The closure creates a local copy for each callback.

Comment: @Guffa Thanks for the clarification. After staring at it for a while, that came to me.

Comment: @Guffa Brilliant, explanation!

Comment: @Zero21xxx Sorry for the vagueness =[

Answer (score 2):

Pass the key as an option to the ajax request, then access it with this.nameofoption.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/html",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            html: "foo",
            delay: 1
        },
        context: {key: i},
        success: function(){
            console.log(this.key);
        }
    });
}
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/R9Ldd/2/

*Updated to use firebuglite*

Comment: +1 Interresting option. However, you have to be carful so that you don't use a property name that the `ajax` method uses. The list seems to grow for each version, so you should perhaps use a property name that you are sure will never be used.

Comment: @Guffa - The only reason I prefer this option over an additional closure is the less code required to do it. The biggest problem I see with this option is it is not documented, and `this` is easily confused with the parent scope's `this` to novice developers. It's definitely important though as you mention to use a name that won't be later used by ajax, such as `loopkey` or `periodkey`.

Comment: Well, it is kind of documented. The documentation for the `context` option says that the default value is the options object, but there is no example for using it this way. Another way is of course to assign the key to the `context` option itself, then it's available as `this` in the callback.

Comment: So i guess a better way would be to pass an object to the context that contained the value.